# Delphi Detect Word version through Registry

Tags: delphi, ms-word, operating-system, registry

I just added this function which determines which mailmerge method to use. It seems to work on XP and Windows 2000. Is there any reason why it wouldn't work on NT, Vista, 7 and other Windows versions? I'm thinking will there be an issue with the registry?

```
function GetMSOfficeVersion: String;
var Reg: TRegistry;
begin
Result := 'Office Version Not Found';
// create the registry object
Reg := TRegistry.Create;
try
// set the root key
Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
// check for Office97
if Reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\8.0', False) then
begin
Result := 'Microsoft Office97';
end;
// check for Office2000
if Reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0', False) then
begin
Result := 'Microsoft Office2000';
end;
// check for OfficeXP -- not sure if this is correct
// you have to verify the key on a machine with OfficeXP
if Reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\10.0', False) then
begin
Result := 'Microsoft OfficeXP(regkey10)';
end;
// check for 11.0
if Reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\11.0', False) then
begin
Result := 'Microsoft OfficeXP(regkey11)';
end;
// check for 12
if Reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0', False) then
begin
Result := 'Microsoft Office2010';
end;
finally
// make sure we free the object we created
Reg.Free;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Try running your app as Administrator on Vista/Win7.

Comment: Also - Even tho it might not be necesarry, you could add `Exit;` after `Result := ...`, that will jump to the Finally, without doing all the other checks. :)

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? is it a security/user related error? Also, the Office\14.0 is Office2010 I think Office\12.0 is 2007.

Comment: One instance of windows can have all the registry entries you mention. if your goal is to get the LATEST version only you should change the order from bigger to lower and exit as Jeff said with a return to not do all those extra validations.

Comment: see my comment below... thanks

Comment: When you always use OLE Automation for the mailmerge, you can simply use `Application.Version`.

Comment: Thanks fox, I can't believe I didn't know about this... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from making sure you create the registry in read-only mode, like TOndrej suggests, you'll also want to fix the version matching in that code, as it is ***wrong***.

Here are the right numbers for the parts where things gets shady in your code fragment:

```
10.0 = Office XP
11.0 = Office 2003
12.0 = Office 2007
13.0 - doesn't exist, obvious Microsoft/US numbering standards.
14.0 = Office 2010
```

Comment: Version 13 doesn't exists for the same reason some buildings don't have a 13th floor.

Comment: Cool thanks ALOT for the breakdown, as the program only reacts for a Word2010 I wouldn't ever have noticed that error. I copied that code from here:http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55296 Can you explain why it correctly reacts to a Word2010 install even though according to your guide it should think I have Word2007

Answer (score 6):

Probably insufficient privileges. Try using [`OpenKeyReadOnly`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly) instead of `OpenKey`.

Comment: OpenKeyReadOnly changes the Access flag, rendering Create(KEY_READ) useless. Just use one approach.

Comment: `OpenKey` will open the key with write access. You don't have write access as a standard user on NT based systems. This answer is the one.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question. I haven't tested the function on any other Windows OS. I was asking the question whether there was any reason why it shouldn't? I suppose if it didn't work you've given me an indication of why

Comment: As a little addendum, you really need to do this on Windows 2000 and XP as well. Lots of users will not be running as a power user, especially in an enterprise environment.

Comment: Hey, I just created another user on my XP PC with restricted non-admin rights, loaded up my App and it stil appears to be able to grab the version from the registry. Is there another way I can test this?

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there any reason why it wouldn't work"*

Yes, individual products may create a `Software\Office\#.0` entry, you should be checking for a `Word` subkey in the specific version's key. Even then, f.i. 'Word Viewer' might have created the Word subkey which wouldn't do mail merge. If you really want to go with the registry better look for `Word.Application` keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Apart from `Word.Application.#` keys the `Word.Application` key itself has a `CurVer` subkey.

(Previously I suggested the below but Fox's comment to the question is much better I think.)

I would directly try to create the automation object, if it fails then that version is not available, fallback to a lower version. Or sth. like:

```
function IsWord14: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    CreateOleObject('Word.Application.14');
  except on E:EOleSysError do
    if E.ErrorCode = HRESULT($800401F3) then  // invalid class string
      Result := False
    else
      raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Sertac I can't believe I didn't know about the Application.Version! but obviously it means creating the OleObject before determining the action. I actually only needed to test whether it's Word2010 and potentially when a new version comes out I'd want to try run with that too. Funnily enough I may not need the version after all but thanks for all the tips :)

Comment: @notidaho - If you have a preferred version and try to create the ole object, if the class string is invalid the creation fails real quick. No harm done. If it doesn't fail, you can use it. :) Anyway, don't check 'office' keys for the reasons I stated, instead read 'CurVer' under 'Word.Application'.

Comment: So I reckon I need a function getMSOfficeVersion: String which just returns the version. I don't fully understand OleObjects... Can I just create a Word.Application to obtain the version, then simply leave it be? or do I have to kill it in someway? And when I need a Windows.Application oleobject later on, must I create it again?

Comment: @notidaho - AFAICT, if you only need to do mail merge you don't need office version but MS Word version. If you keep a reference to an ole object you can use it later, otherwise the object will be freed when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by out of scope? I've just realised after I mailmerge once, I have two instances of WINWORD in the systray, because I'm creating an oleobject each time i check the version. I need to either create and use only one, or be able to kill them after creation. Thanks (and sorry to drag on)

Comment: @notidaho - A local variable (defined in a procedure f.i.) goes out of scope when that procedure returns. If you have `var Word: OleVariant` in a procedure which is assigned an automation object, the object is cleared at the end of that procedure.

Comment: Is that the same for a local variable defined in a function? I believe the Word := CreateOleObject(Word.Application) wasn't being cleared, and I had to free it with Word.Quit(False);

Comment: @notidaho - Yes, a function is really a procedure. The automation object is cleared when it goes out of scope, not the application instance. For that to happen you have to ask it to quit like you're doing.